# Copy list B to list A when A and B contain the same fields

Tags: c#

I saw a method that copies the fields between two **different** objects but with **identical fields**.

The question is there a way to copy a **list of A** to a **list of B**?

```
    public class A
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }      
  
    public Main()
    {
        B b = new B { X = 10, Y = 2 };
        A a = new A();
        CopyProperties(b, a); // it works

        List<B> listB = new List<B> { new B { X = 5, Y = 4 } };
        List<A> listA = new List<A>();
        CopyProperties(listB, listA); // it doesn't work
    }  

    public static Target CopyProperties<Source, Target>(Source source, Target target)
    {
        foreach (var sProp in source.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            bool isMatched = target.GetType().GetProperties().Any(tProp => tProp.Name == sProp.Name && tProp.GetType() == sProp.GetType() && tProp.CanWrite);
            if (isMatched)
            {
                var value = sProp.GetValue(source);
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = target.GetType().GetProperty(sProp.Name);
                propertyInfo.SetValue(target, value);
             }
         }
         return target;
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
List<B> listB = new List<B> { new B { X = 5, Y = 4 } };
List<A> listA = listB.Select(x => CopyProperties(x, new A()).ToList();
```

This iterates `listB`, creates a new instance of `A` for each entry of the list, copies the entry of `listB` into the newly created instance and stores them in a new list.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rfL3fn